# Write a custom validation method to prevent bots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I'm trying to add a validation to my User model.

I want to prevent people which mail is present in a "Bot" table to register.

The Bot table structure is:

```
create_table "bots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "banned_domains"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I'm using Devise for registration, and I want to add a validation that check if "email domain is present in the bot table" the record is not valid.

The method to validate is this:

```
def is_a_bot?(user_email)
 Bot.where("banned_domains LIKE (?)", "%#{user_email}%").present?
end
```

How can I add a validation using this method of the "email" attribute of my user model?

Comment: Can you provide some example values from the `banned_domains` field?

Comment: For example "stack.ru"

Comment: Shouldn't the field be called `banned_domain` rather than `banned_domains` then?  The plural is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Add this validation to your User class

```
#in User
before_create :check_not_a_bot

def check_not_a_bot
  if Bot.find_by_banned_domains(self.email.split("@").last)
    self.errors.add(:email, "domain exists in list of banned domains")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Define method in the Bot model like that

```
self.is_a_bot?(user_email)
 Bot.where("banned_domains LIKE (?)", "%#{user_email}%").present?
end
```

then in the User model you can use validates or before_create method (for example)

```
before_create :check_bot_email

def check_bot_email
  if Bot.is_a_bot?(self.email)
    errors.add(:base, "The user is a bot")
  end
end
```